# Divide entire DataFrame based on dates in specific columns into quarterly dataframes

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

New to pandas.

Have a DataFrame of the order:
`A B C Date1 Date2 D` with multiple rows with values. I want to divide the entire DataFrame into multiple dataframes based on quarters, i.e `(Jan-Mar, Apr-Jun, Jul-Sep, Oct-Dec)`. I am trying to use only the Date1 column values for the same. I tried the following so far:

`data_q = data.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper(freq = '3M'))`

The dates are in the form 2009-11-03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a few ways to do this.

I would ensure that `Date1` column is a datetime type using the `.dtype` method.

e.g. `df['Date1'].dtype`

If it's not, cast to datetime object using:

```
df.Date1 = pd.to_datetime(df.Date1)
```

Add a quarters column for eventual data frame slicing:

```
df['quarters'] = df.Date1.dt.quarter
```

Create your data frames:

```
q1 = df[df.quarters == 1]
q2 = df[df.quarters == 2]
q3 = df[df.quarters == 3]
q4 = df[df.quarters == 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the approach that appears easiest to me is to convert `Date1` to your index, then `groupby` on the quarter.

```
df2 = df.set_index('Date1')
quardfs = list(df2.groupby(df2.index.quarter))
```

This will leave you with quardfs, which a list of `DataFrames`.

If you don't want to set `Date1` to an index, you can also copy it out of the `DataFrame` and use it:

```
quars = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date1']).quarter
quardfs = list(df2.groupby(quars))
```