# Fill in missing column values based on pattern in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to fill in missing values in specific columns based on quarters.

**Data**

```
type    date    stat  test
aa      Q1 2022 20    1
aa      Q2 2022 10    2
aa      Q3 2022 30    1
bb      Q1 2022 30    1
bb      Q2 2022 10    1
```

**Desired**

```
type    date    stat  test
aa      Q1 2022 20    1
aa      Q2 2022 10    2
aa      Q3 2022 30    1
aa      Q4 2022 0
bb      Q1 2022 30    1
bb      Q2 2022 10    1
bb      Q3 2022 0
bb      Q4 2022 0
```

**Doing**

```
Logic:

The pattern is Q1 2022, Q2 2022, Q3 2022 and Q4 2022. 
If there is a 'break' in this pattern, the missing data should fill in accordingly with a stat 
value of 0.
```

I believe I can create a dictionary and then combine the impute function

```
data = {  "Q1 2022":0 ,
          "Q2 2022":0 ,
          "Q3 2022":0 ,
          "Q4 2022":0 ,
       }



df["type"].fillna("", inplace = True) 
df["date"].fillna("", inplace = True)   #input dictionary mapping
df["stat"].fillna("0", inplace = True)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You can use a combination `pd.to_datetime` and `resample`, I suppose.

Comment: ah ok will try this thank you

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122793/divide-entire-dataframe-based-on-dates-in-specific-columns-into-quarterly-datafr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new dataframe with all combinations of `type` and `dates` then merge it with your original dataframe. Finally, fill values according your rules:

```
from itertools import product

dates = ['Q1 2022', 'Q2 2022', 'Q3 2022', 'Q4 2022']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(product(df['type'].unique(), dates), columns=['type', 'date'])
df1 = df1.merge(df, how='left').fillna({'stat': 0, 'test': ''})
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  type     date  stat test
0   aa  Q1 2022  20.0  1.0
1   aa  Q2 2022  10.0  2.0
2   aa  Q3 2022  30.0  1.0
3   aa  Q4 2022   0.0     
4   bb  Q1 2022  30.0  1.0
5   bb  Q2 2022  10.0  1.0
6   bb  Q3 2022   0.0     
7   bb  Q4 2022   0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `pivot` first then `reindex` back

```
l =['Q1 2022','Q2 2022','Q3 2022','Q4 2022']
out = df.pivot(*df).reindex(columns = l,fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(name = 'stat')
```

Comment: thank you for some reason it skips 'Q3 2022' - I updated your script to:
l =['Q1 2022','Q2 2022','Q3 2022','Q4 2022']  @BENY

Comment: @Lynn cool, I updated as well ~

Comment: ok thank you- it seems not to follow the pattern though when ran. I am researching. thank you

Comment: I think it doesn't work since @Lynn added the new column `test`. It raises `TypeError: pivot() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`.

Comment: It did not work as shown before the addition